# Why was Ruminawi not eligible to the throne?

Tags: inca

Ruminawi was not eligible for the throne although being son of Wayna Capac and queen (of Pillaro) Choazanguil ([source](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rumi%C3%B1ahui)).

Atahualpa was his half-brother, same father Wayna Capac, but by mother had princess (of Quito) [Paccha Duchicela](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paccha_Duchicela).

Both seem to have noble lineage mothers. Why was Atahualpa the chosen one instead of Ruminawi when he was first-born? (And sorry: How accurate are those WP articles on the topic?).

**Edit**: From the source: *era hijo bastardo de Huayna Capac y Atahualpa era el legítimo heredero después de Ninan Cuyuchi y Huascar* (translated: *was bastard son of Huayna Capac and Atahualpa was the legitimate heir after Ninan Cuyuchi and Huascar*). It says somehow that due to being bastard son he was not *legitimate* heir like Atahualpa, Huascar, and Ninan Cuyuchi were.

Comment: Does it actually say he was "**in**eligible"? **Incan succession doesn't default to firstborn son**; but they were all still eligible. It seems to me that he simply wasn't chosen, not that he couldn't be chosen.

Comment: Let me edit the question with part of the translation

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest that he was not chosen, not due to his status, but due to the politics favoring Atahualpa.  The link you provided on the princess/consort Paccha Duchicela states:

> Her rights to the throne of Quito was thereby transferred to the
>   royal Inca dynasty

By selecting Atahualpa as heir, the Quito territory was added to the empire much like any political marriage of Monarchs in Europe.  So politics, not birthright.

Comment: Sounds plausible to me.